TypeError: KaplanMeierFitter.fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'duration'
I'm trying to use Kaplan Meier Estimator in my python 3.10.12. My data set looks like
| duration |Paid_off|
|          |        |
---------------------
| 19.0     | 1      |
| 24.0     | 0      |

I have written following python code
from lifelines import KaplanMeierFitter
data_kmf=KaplanMeierFitter()
data_kmf.fit(duration=data_df["duration"],event_observed=data_df["paid_off"])

But I'm getting error saying
TypeError: KaplanMeierFitter.fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'duration'
Can you please help me to resolve the error?

The argument appears to be named durations, not duration, as shown in the documentation.
